# How do send cookie when clicking on a link?

Tags: php, rest, cookies

I have this rest api that I need to use in my PHP code. Basically, I need to run the authentication API (let's call it API-1) to get 2 cookies. Using the 2 cookies that I got from API-1, I will then need to call the next API (let's call it API-2) to get the zip file.

When I tried calling API-1 to get the cookies in Postman rest client followed by keying in the URL of the API-2 on Chrome, I am able to start the download of the zip file. There's no authentication error here since I already got the cookies stored in Chrome when I ran API-1 before I run API-2.

Now my question is how do I make sure that I can create a link (URL of API-2) and pass the cookies when the user click on the link. I want the user to be able to download the zip file after he clicked on the link. The cookies needs to be passed so that I can avoid the authentication error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

for send cookie with header use :

```
header("Set-Cookie: SIDNAME=$overwrite; path=/; secure");
```

for redirect to url use this :

```
header('Location: http://www.homeyli.com/');
```

Comment: Hi! I tried that but it didn't work properly for me. The page that runs API-1 is using a separate domain name from the URL of API-2.